# Existential quantifier equivalent of a universal quantifier statement.

Tags: predicate-logic

My question is this, for the following sentence: Every pet has an owner , when translated into predicate logic gives $\forall x\enspace(P(x) \rightarrow O(x))$, but what is the equivalent with a $\exists x$ instead of $\forall x$? Is there a general rule when changing between the two?

Comment: I don't know what $P$ and $O$ stand for, but taking the natural interpretation, your statement says that every pet is an owner, which isn't what you want.

Comment: for all $x$ $P(x)$ is the same as not not for all $x$ $P(x)$, which is the same as not there exists x such that not $P(x)$.

Comment: OK, if $O(x)$ means '$x$  has an owner', it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negation of a universal statement is an existential statement:
$\lnot \forall x A \equiv \exists x \neg A$.

Thus, in your case this would be:
$$ 
\forall x ( P(x)\to O(x))\equiv \lnot (\exists x\lnot (P(x)\to O(x))) \equiv \lnot (\exists x(P(x)\land \neg O(x)))\,.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Negate the negation of $\forall x . P(x) \Longrightarrow O(x)$, where:

$P(x)$ means x is a pet;

$O(x)$ means x has an owner.

Comment: so it would be simply be ∃x(-P(x)⟹-O(x)) where - is a negation? Does the implication remain when negating it?

Comment: To negate $\forall x . P(x) \Longrightarrow O(x)$, first place a negation symbol in front of it all. Perhaps it would be best to read up on negating predicate and propositional phrases. I can lead you through it, but that wouldn't be fair to you.

Comment: - ∀x.(P(x)⟹O(x)) which becomes ∃x-(P(x)⟹O(x)) ?

Comment: $\neg [\forall x . P(x) \Longrightarrow O(x)] \equiv \exists . \neg[P(x) \Longrightarrow O(x)]$.

Comment: ∃.¬[P(x)⟹O(x)] ≡ ∃.[P(x) ∧ ¬O(x)] ?

Comment: Yes. Now. since we know that for any proposition $Z(x)$ that $\neg \neg Z(x) \equiv Z(x)$, then you can place a negation symbol in front of $\exists  x . P(x) \wedge \neg O(x)$ to get the original phrase you came up with.